# Low memory memory full notification keep popping up

Tags: insufficient-memory

How do I restore the memory in my Huawei cell phone I keep getting memory full notification

Comment: Uninstall sonme apps already!!

Comment: For a starter: Check with the first-aid and links provided from our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info). If you cannot solve your issue that way, you will need to [edit] your post and give more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can try following:

1. Uninstall Apps
2. Move apps to external storage or money card. You can do that by going to app settings. You may be able to move some apps by app settings option.
3. If you're still getting low memory issue, then you use [This app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ljmobile.move.app&hl=en&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Dmove%20to%20sd%20card%20app&pcampaignid=APPU_1_lBMtWM6GMYm4apmwq5AH). This is only app I found on play store which can move those apps to SD card which android app settings couldn't. But to use this, you need to be **rooted**.